# How to print factorial series?

Tags: php, algorithm, function

I want to know how to print factorial in php. I have try to search on Google but unable to find result with solid prove example (Php Code). I find this forloop, i'm not satisfy with this.

```
for($c=3; $c>=1;$c--){
        for($d=$c; $d>=1; $d--){
        echo $c;
            }// for ends
            echo "<br />";
    }// for ends
```

Out Put `333 22 1`

I want this printed as output:

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
```

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com I think it is use in php

Comment: Goto php.ini file Uncomment the line `extension=php_gmp.dll` . Check here too http://php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php     . You said only : `Hi, Its Not working`. You need to uncomment extension line from php.ini , which is pretty Simple. Please dont say its not working before trying yourself : `Why its not working` !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For calculating factorial,

```
function factorial($in) {
    return array_product(range(1, $in));
}
```

and use it like,

```
echo factorial(5);
```

---

If you want to print factorial,

```
function factorial_print($in) {
    return implode(' * ', array_reverse(range(1, $in)));
}
```

and use it like,

```
echo factorial_print(5);
```

Comment: it does not working, it is giving me out put `120` when i put `factorial(5)` i think it should return `5 * 4* 3* 2*1`

Comment: @ayazkhan 5! === 120 what is the issue?

Comment: i think OP not clearly expressed what he wants as output, he wants `5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1` printed as output

Answer (score 1):

Calculating a factorial is pretty straightforward, and doesn't need recursion either:

```
function factorial($x) {
    $r = 1;
    for ($i = 2; $i <= $x; ++$i) {
        $r *= $i;
    }
    return $r;
}

echo factorial(10), PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: Thats what i thought first and answered, but then i understood, OP wants representation of factorials or he is not clear about the question ` 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 `

Comment: after correcting spelling `functional` i cannot compile it, it says unexpected '$r', im curious what `$r *= *$i;` does !

Comment: `$r *= $i;` simply multiplies `$r` by `$i` and stores the result in `$r`.... it's documented under [assignment operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php) in the PHP docs

Comment: yes, i know that, there is one more typo in your code, i guess `$r *= *$i;` needs to be `$r *= $i;`, also you need to place `return $r;` at last

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
function factorial($number) { 

    if ($number < 2) { 
        return 1; 
    } else { 
        return ($number * factorial($number-1)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: it does not working, it is giving me out put `3628800` when i put `factorial(10)`

Comment: According to me its giving right digit, according to you what would be the factorial of 10 ?

Comment: You should have to calculate it manually & cross check it, also you can match the digits here https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/factorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Use following function inbuilt in PHP.

```
$fact1 = gmp_fact(5); // 5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1
echo gmp_strval($fact1) . "\n";
```

For more refer **[HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-fact.php)**

Comment: You need to Install extension , check http://serverfault.com/questions/429585/how-to-install-enable-gmp-math-functions-for-php-on-ubuntu for linux , google for windows

Comment: Goto php.ini file Uncomment the line `extension=php_gmp.dll` . Check here too http://php.net/manual/en/gmp.installation.php